# Database of formalized english sentences?

Tags: resource-request, logic, formal-semantics, datasets

(Not sure if this is the right site to ask)

Is there an online (preferably free) database of English sentences and the corresponding first-order representations?

Comment: It is generally OK to ask for language resources here. You can also consider asking on [opendata.se] (as you are interested in Open Data).